# What is the trick to parsing a C assignment-expression with no backtracking?

Tags: c, parsing, grammar, backtracking, bnf

Parsing a C `assignment-expression` top-down has to choose between a `conditional-expression` and a `unary-expression`.  The (unfortunately complicated) BNF is:

```
<assignment-expression>     ::= <conditional-expression>
                              | <unary-expression> <assignment-operator> <assignment-expression>
<conditional-expression>    ::= <logical-or-expression> 
                              | <logical-or-expression> ? <expression> : <conditional-expression>
<logical-or-expression>     ::= <logical-and-expression> 
                              | <logical-or-expression> || <logical-and-expression>
<logical-and-expression>    ::= <inclusive-or-expression> 
                              | <logical-and-expression> && <inclusive-or-expression>
<inclusive-or-expression>   ::= <exclusive-or-expression> 
                              | <inclusive-or-expression> '|' <exclusive-or-expression>
<exclusive-or-expression>   ::= <and-expression> 
                              | <exclusive-or-expression> ^ <and-expression>
<and-expression>            ::= <equality-expression> 
                              | <and-expression> & <equality-expression>
<equality-expression>       ::= <relational-expression> 
                              | <equality-expression> == <relational-expression> 
                              | <equality-expression> != <relational-expression>
<relational-expression>     ::= <shift-expression>
                              | <relational-expression> < <shift-expression>
                              | <relational-expression> > <shift-expression>
                              | <relational-expression> <= <shift-expression>
                              | <relational-expression> >= <shift-expression>
<shift-expression>          ::= <additive-expression>
                              | <shift-expression> << <additive-expression>
                              | <shift-expression> >> <additive-expression>
<additive-expression>       ::= <multiplicative-expression>
                              | <additive-expression> + <multiplicative-expression>
                              | <additive-expression> - <multiplicative-expression>
<multiplicative-expression> ::= <cast-expression>
                              | <multiplicative-expression> * <cast-expression>
                              | <multiplicative-expression> / <cast-expression>
                              | <multiplicative-expression> % <cast-expression>
<cast-expression>           ::= <unary-expression>
                              | ( <type-name> ) <cast-expression>
<unary-expression>          ::= <postfix-expression>
                              | ++ <unary-expression>
                              | -- <unary-expression>
                              | <unary-operator> <cast-expression>
                              | sizeof <unary-expression>
                              | sizeof <type-name>
<postfix-expression>        ::= <primary-expression>
                              | <postfix-expression> [ <expression> ]
                              | <postfix-expression> ( {<assignment-expression>}* )
                              | <postfix-expression> . <identifier>
                              | <postfix-expression> -> <identifier>
                              | <postfix-expression> ++
                              | <postfix-expression> --
<primary-expression>        ::= <identifier>
                              | <constant>
                              | <string>
                              | ( <expression> )
```

Note that a `unary-expression` satisfies the `cast-expression` rule.

If the input is `X=3` and the parser tries the `conditional-expression` branch first then the input satisfies the `primary-expression` rule by simply stopping at `X`.  The parser would have to backtrack and consider the `unary-expression assignment-operator assignment-expression` branch to discover the `=3` part.

If the input is `X==Y` and the parser tries the `unary-expression` branch first then the `assignment-operator` is never found and the parser would have to backtrack and consider the `conditional-expression` branch to discover the `equality-expression` rule.

I don't see how to left-factor the BNF anywhere to avoid backtracking.  Are recursion and backtracking unavoidable?  Or is there a trick?

**EDIT:**
In response to the comment requesting a reduced grammar, the following will demonstrate the `X=3` vs. `X==Y` problem, but only to demonstrate how the reduced grammar requires backtracking, for people who don't wish to grok the full grammar. Whatever fix is made to avoid backtracking in this reduced grammar might not be possible with the full grammar.

```
<assignment-expression>     ::= <conditional-expression>
                              | <unary-expression> <assignment-operator> <unary-expression>
<conditional-expression>    ::= <unary-expression> == <unary-expression>
<unary-expression>          ::= <identifier>
<assignment_operator>       ::= '='
```

If the input is `X=3` and the parser looks for `conditional-expression` first, `==` isn't found so the parser has to backtrack, while the input `X==Y` works with no backtracking.

If the input is `X=3` and the parse looks for `unary-expression` first, the input is acceptable, while the input `X==Y` will require backtracking to match `conditional-expression`.

Comment: Does it actually backtrack? I feel, in the compiled version, the decision would actually happen on the character after the first `=`. It reads the first `=`, knows this is now assignment or conditional. Reading the next character tells it which. (I'm not an expert, so...)

Comment: I'm not convinced that reformulating a grammar for `C` into a form that allows for top-down parsing is possible.

Comment: Please consider making a [mcve]. No, really. We don't need all of C's 143 operator priorities and their mother-in-law to understand the issue. Make a short, *complete* grammar that demonstrates it.

Comment: @Ouroborus If a parser doesn't backtrack using the above grammar, things could go wrong. A top-down parser won't typically consider the tokens after `X` until it finishes determining `X` is a `primary-expression`.  If the chosen starting candidate rule was `conditional-expression` then the parser thinks `X` is a `conditional-expression`, and it won't look for the `=` at all, which would be a bug.  If the starting candidate was `unary-expression`, the `assignment-expression` rule tells it to look for `assignment-operator` next, and the parser correctly finds `=`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError That's my concern.  If you can find any online proof or discussion, please let me know.  The majority of C can be parsed without backtracking, but `assignment-expression`, `compound-statement`, `external-declaration`, `parameter-declaration`, and `specifier-qualifier` in the full C grammar look like problems.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI The problem with reducing the grammar is that it becomes easier to introduce tricks such as left-factoring that might be impossible to put in the full grammar.  Nevertheless, I've added a reduced grammar to demonstrate the `X=3` vs. `X==Y` problem, but only to show how the reduced grammar requires backtracking. Whatever fix is made to avoid backtracking in the reduced grammar might not be possible with the full grammar.

Comment: The simplified grammar is not a problem for a bottom-up parser such ad LALR(1) and we know that the full C grammar is not a problem for such parsers either (everyone and their dog has a yacc grammar for some version of C). If you want top-down parsing you need to refactor it. Now what is the question? How do you/can you refactor this specific grammar, or how do you/can you refactor any grammar suited for a bottom-up parser?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI The question is how to parse a C `assignment-expression` top-down with no backtracking.

Comment: You don't parse C assignment-expression top-down with no backtracking using this grammar. It is not suitable for top-down parsing with no backtracking. A suitable grammar will have different productions with different non-terminal symbols. To refactor, you need to expand the leftmost non-terminal of each ambiguous rule until you arrive at a set of rules that all start with the same thing. Then you factor the common beginning out to its own rule, rinse and repeat. This is not a trick, this is the method. If you are stuck, ask about the place you are stuck at.

Comment: For the simplified grammar, you will expand the rules until you get assignment-expression := unary-expression = unary-expression | unary-expression == unary-expression. Then you refactor to assignment-expression := unary-expression continue-assignment and continue-assignment := == unary-expression | = unary-expression.

Comment: Sorry I avoided terms like left-factoring but now I see you are familiar with them. I could have said the same thing in way less words. Do left-factor, it is not a trick, it is the way of life.

Comment: I don't think the rules you show will be difficult to convert, but you will encounter a problem with cast-expression. If you see a '(' you need to know whether you have a type-name or an expression inside. And you don't know without potentially unlimited lookahead. Either one can start with any number of `(`s. You *might* be able to left-factor it, but the result probably won't be pretty and will not resemble the original grammar.

Comment: On the second thought, cast-expression is not such a big problem because type-name seemingly cannot start with `(` (I initially thought that it can). But the refactored grammar will probably be very ugly. If you strictly need top-down parsing, then perhaps you can solve it in a different way. C grammar looks this way because it wants to disallow things like `a + b = 2`, but you can easily allow such expressions at the grammar level and filter them out at the semantic level.